# is it possible to query the cost of sms or call in SINCH?

Tags: sinch, sinch-verification

Hi currently our project is using sinch ios sdk and implementing sending sms and calls- through verifyCode:completionHandler and initiateWithCompletionHandler .
i as a backend developer needs to get the price/cost of each sms and call through rest API 
how can i do this  ?

Answer (score 1):

use this, you should use callbacks for a few reasons like security. But take advantage of that callback and also log the price.
    [RequestBody]
    {
        string - id
        string - event
        string - method
        identity - identity
        money - price
        string? - reference
        string? - custom
        string[]? - acceptLanguage
    }

https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/rest/#VerificationRequestEvent

Comment: thank you for your feedback , according to the url you send we need to get the verification callback url how can we get it ?